# How do you convert a Javascript timestamp into UTC format?

Tags: javascript, datetime

For example if you receive a timestamp in Javascript:

**1291656749000**

How would you create a function to convert the timestamp into UTC like:

**2010/12/6 05:32:30pm**

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
(new Date(1291656749000)).toUTCString()
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Note that the parameter sent to Date() must be in milliseconds.

Comment: how to do just the opposite of this? i.e. convert UTC string to timestamp?

Comment: How about convert the timestamp into GMT

Comment: isnt it that GMT and UTC are in the same values @askingsomequestion

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **(new Date(integer)).toUTCString()**,

but if you have to have the 'pm', you can format it yourself:

```
function utcformat(d){
    d= new Date(d);
    var tail= 'GMT', D= [d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth()+1, d.getUTCDate()],
    T= [d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds()];
    if(+T[0]> 12){
        T[0]-= 12;
        tail= ' pm '+tail;
    }
    else tail= ' am '+tail;
    var i= 3;
    while(i){
        --i;
        if(D[i]<10) D[i]= '0'+D[i];
        if(T[i]<10) T[i]= '0'+T[i];
    }
    return D.join('/')+' '+T.join(':')+ tail;
}
```

**alert(utcformat(1291656749000))**

/*  returned value: (String)
2010/12/06 05:32:29 pm GMT
*/