# Stop Javascript DateTime adjusting to local time zone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

I am receiving the correct unix time that I use in my html page in my javascript. However, when I view or alert the unixtime, what happens is that the date is adjusted based on my desktop's current timezone, but I need the DateTime to be without the timezone.

This is how I pass the data in my javascript, one of the many ways I use the unixtime:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var a = <?php echo "1434203820"; // an example only?>;
var date = new Date(a);
alert(date);

});

</script>
```

what the unix time should show is:

> Jun 13 2015 13:57 (if it was converted)

but it is showing this date:

> Jun 13 2015 21:57 malay peninsula time

What basically happens is that the javascript gets my local time zone and converts that date to that time zone. How could I force it(and all other javascript functions that I use) to use the original time it supposed to be showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the UTC format you can use one of the many UTC methods. For instance you could use [`Date.prototype.toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString):

```js
var unixTS = 1434203820 * 1000; // JS date is in millseconds
var date = new Date(unixTS);

document.write(date.toUTCString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is converting back the timestamp to UTC format ?

[How do you convert a Javascript timestamp into UTC format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380469/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-timestamp-into-utc-format)

Comment: For future reference to mark a question as a duplicate use the `flag` link directly under the body of the OP's question.