# Javascript convert string to date, but ignore the timezone that is assumed it's in

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

A really long title, I know, but I had to highlight the fact, that I'm confronting a situation that's a little different than all the usual javascript date conversions.

I am getting the following datetime in a string from the server:

> 2017-05-18T08:00:00

When I put this string into the following statement:

```
var newDate = new Date("2017-05-18T08:00:00");
```

It assumes it's in the UTC timezone, so it automatically adjusts, and converts it into local time, which in Sidney would become **2017/05/18 18:00:00**.

Any way that I can stop the date constructor to assume that the string is UTC time (make it assume that it's local time)?

Comment: can you append -10:00 to the end?

Comment: This question is covered in many different places [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181524/how-do-you-preserve-a-javascript-dates-time-zone-from-browser-to-server-and-ba), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771609/how-to-ignore-users-time-zone-and-force-date-use-specific-time-zone?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127544/stop-javascript-datetime-adjusting-to-local-time-zone?rq=1) to name a few

Comment: Any chance you can fix the server so it gives you the ISO 8601 string with time zone? It's an anti-pattern to expect consumers to know where the server is located.

Comment: "2017-05-18T08:00:00" should be parsed as local, not UTC, so there's one example of why you shouldn't use the built-in parser. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results?s=1|7.9852).

Answer (score 1):

use `getTimezoneOffset()` function to adjust timezone. By default Date converts it to local timezone :(

Comment: Thanks. Using it like this works:  new Date(new Date(timestampStr).getTime() + (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000))

Comment: This is a bad idea. The OP behaviour is not standards compliant, so adjusting by the timezone offset will mean the result is wrong in standards compliant hosts (which is quite a few).

Answer (score 0):

If you're applying your code in serious applications, consider a tool like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks! This helped!

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer.