# convert local timezone timestamp to UTC timestamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp

My server returns date data as local timezone timestamps.

On the client-side, I want to display those dates as local date strings. If I do the following, I got the wrong date ("6/30/2014" instead of "7/01/2014")

```
var ts = 1404172800;
new Date(1404172800*1000).toLocaleDateString()
>>>"6/30/2014"
```

To prevent this problem, I suppose I have to convert the local timezone timestramp I receive from the server to UTC timestamp before creating the `new Date()` object.

Am I right? What is the best way to achieve that that will work in most browsers?

**Edit**:

I confirm that the real date in local time zone should be 7/01/2014. That's local Eastern time UTC -5(-4). but the `new Date()` object thinks this is UTC but it's not. I suppose it's because the date is returned as a timestamp without having been converted to UTC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a Javascript timestamp into UTC format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380469/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-timestamp-into-utc-format)

Comment: `6/30/2014` *could* be correct.

Comment: I confirm that the real date in local time zone should be 7/01/2014. That's local Eastern time UTC -5(-4). but the new Date() object thinks this is UTC but it's not. I suppose the problem is that the date is returned as a timestamp without having been converted to UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that right already? [Timestamps are always in UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853977/unix-timestamp-always-in-gmt).

You're seeing 30th June and not 1st of July because when that event happened, in the *local* time zone, it was still 30th of June. For example, for me it is showing as 1st of July in IST.

[image]

Also, this timestamp represents an event which occurred at 1st July 2014 at 00:00:00 GMT exactly. India is GMT+05:30, as you can see in the screenshot - so if the *local* timezone, even if it is GMT minus one minute, it would still be 30th of June there.

Comment: I confirm that the real date in local time zone should be 7/01/2014. That's local. but the new Date() object thinks this is UTC but it's not.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar What's the local time zone?

Comment: Eastern time UTC -5(-4). The problem, I suppose is that the date is returned as a timestamp without having been converted to UTC

Comment: Date takes in a timestamp, timestamps are always UTC, your timestamp 1404172800000 translates to 1st July 2014 00:00:00, your timezone is UTC -5, which translates this to 30th June 2014 19:00:00, so your code works fine. If you're still positive this is producing the wrong result, you need to check your server side code.

Comment: Ok you are right! Timestamp should always be in UTC so I should work on server side