# How to convert the local browser time to utc time unsing moment.js

Tags: node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

Tried multiple methods to convert the local time to UTC. Tried Offset(420) as the time difference is UTC 7 and it worked. So here what i need is my users will be giving a request from different timezones and all of them should convert to UTC. So when giving time from different timezone the UTC time difference will also change how it can be identified and change accordingly. how can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert local timezone timestamp to UTC timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647864/convert-local-timezone-timestamp-to-utc-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.utc()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) to get UTC time. If you wish to send it to the server, it's probably best to send as an [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string.

```js
const localDate = moment();
const utcDate = moment.utc();
console.log("Local time:", localDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
console.log("UTC time:", utcDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```